# Java Toolkit and Dimension classes

Tags: java, swing, interface, jframe, graphic

I've just started learning a few things about graphic interfaces in Java and I don't understand some methods from the `Toolkit` class.

For example `Toolkit` class has this method:

```
abstract Dimension getScreenSize()
```

I don't understand how this method has a return type of another class? is this a concept in programming?

And I've seen that if I want to call this method I'll do something like this:

```
Dimension dim = tk.getScreenSize();
```

Is this something similar to polymorphism?

Comment: It's not polymorphism, you may have some other class let's call it `Operations` and you may have some methods that return `int` or `double` for example (`sum()` or `divide()`) it's the same concept, just that it involves other classes instead of primitive types

Comment: Thanks for answering! i guess i just have to get more familiar with those couse i've never seen methods like that and i didnt knew that you can store in a reference from class A a method from class B for example. Do you know where i can find more examples similar to that one?

Comment: Everywhere, try making programs instead of reading, you'll get more familiar that way than just by reading

Answer (score 0):

The return type of a method is anything that extends Object, including int (Integer), float (Float), String and etc..

In this case the API returns a Dimension object, it holds the values getWidth() and getHeight().

A sample:

```
public class Dimension {
    private final int width, height;
    public Dimension(int w, int h) { width = w; height = h; }
    public int getWidth() { return width; }
    public int getHeight() { return height; }
}
```

Then in other class

```
 public class Toolkit {
       public Dimension getSize(){ return new Dimension(600, 400); }
 }
```

So in the usage:

```
public static void main(String...args) {
      Dimension d = new Toolkit().getSize();
      System.out.println(d.getWidth());
      System.out.println(d.getHeight());
}
```

Comment: Please vote-up if it helps and accept the answer if it solved your problem